# How to run multiple statement in crystal report?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am use crystal report-11
I want run multiple statement back to back using `Add Command`.

Statement -1. `exec schema.gen_statement_data('MS0001','1-Nov-2013','15-Nov-2013')`.

This procedure insert specific record in table.
 Now I want fetch record from this table using 'Add Command' using -

Statement -2.`select * from table_name where date between '1-Nov-2013' and '15-Nov-2013'`.

So I want to call this statements back to back using 'Add Command'.
Please give me a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think statement 1 is possible in crystal reports but yes statement 2 is possible to run in add command in crystal reports.